# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

Tags: php, email, mandrill

```
Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP connect() failed.
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

I used mandrillAPI to send email. It works on my localhost. I can send mails from my localhost. But when I used this on the test server it is not connecting to the mandrill server. It shows the above error. I checked the port and it is open. I can use gmail smtp from my server. It works fine. But I need to use mandrillAPI. I also added DKIM and SPF record on domain. But still not connecting to the smtp.mandrillapi.com
here is the code I used.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;        // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Debugoutput='html';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'apikey';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'example';
$mail->AddAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Nidheesh');  // Add a recipient
         // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('example@gmail.com');

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

`

Comment: Does it work from the command line? Can you connect on that port using telnet or something?

Comment: I can connect. This was either transient or your outgoing firewall/proxy is not passing port 587.

Comment: Everything is working fine in my localhost. The problem occur only on the test server. From test server it is not connecting to smtp.mandrillapp.com